# S3FS S3 module image source issue

Tags: 7, files

I'm using the [S3FS](https://www.drupal.org/project/s3fs) module to use an AWS S3 bucket as my **sites/default/files** directory.
When I upload images they are successfully uploading to the bucket.

I edit a node and include the same images via ckeditor in page content and save my node but when I view the page the images fail to load. The network tab shows 503 errors against the images I am trying to display. I attached a screen shot below:
[image]

When I inspect the node content I find that each of the images src is a relative path and when I right-click and open in a new tab, it attempts to open the image using the website domain rather than a S3 url.

Can anyone help me understand and resolve this issue?

**UPDATE: **

I added the following to settings.php in an attempt to correct the domain of the images but it did not have the desired effect:

```
$conf['s3fs_root_folder'] = 'https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/my.test.bucket';
$conf['s3fs_domain'] = 'https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/my.test.bucket';
```

I haven't information describing the various settings effects so the abouve was a guess.

Comment: You probably have a misconfiguration, have a read at the [README.txt](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/s3fs/blob/7.x-2.x/README.txt)

Comment: @NoSssweat: I agree but I am not able to determine the correct use of a lot of the configuration settings. I updated my question.

Comment: I don't use this module, so I can't really help you. Follow this blog [Easy Amazon S3 in Drupal with S3FS](https://www.symphonythemes.com/drupal-blog/easy-amazon-s3-drupal-s3fs)  perhaps step 6 is what you need. You should also remove the conf you just added, you did it wrong by looking at the readme file. Plus apparently you don't really need to add anything to settings.php for it to work.